Swapping images on hover without affecting the layout
Long story short, I have a dropdown menu with 3 images as cigarettes(250x34). When I hover over them they change into cigarettes with smoke(250x222). When hovering thought, they second images pushes down the other images. I understand the difference in height, but the images are both png and I expected to work. Any tip or help would be very much appreciated.
I know its something about the difference height but i cant find what it is.
This is the html code
 <div class="dropdown">
        <img src="images/anaduomeno.png" alt="Clickable Image" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton">
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
            <a href="clothes.html " target="_blank"><img src="images/clothes.png" id="image1" class="dropdown-icon"></a>
            <a href="about.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/about.png" id="image2" class="dropdown-icon"></a>
            <a href="contact.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/contact.png" id="image3" class="dropdown-icon"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
 


The css code:
#dropdownMenuButton{
  width: 130px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Edw editarw to dropdown menu(icon) */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* To hover tou dropdown */
.dropdown:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Edw clickarw to dropdown kai ginetai responsive */
.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px; 
}

/* Edw vrisketai to periexomeno tou dropdown */
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  min-width: 50px;
}

/* Edw vrisketai to a href tou menu */
.dropdown-menu a {
  display: block;
}

#image1,#image2,#image3{
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 44px;
  
  
}

/* Dropdown icon hover effect */
.dropdown-icon {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.dropdown-icon:hover {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  
}


And lastly the js code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const dropdownIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-icon');
    const newImages = [
        "images/clothesSmoke.png",  // Update these paths
        "images/aboutSmoke.png",  // Update these paths
        "images/contactSmoke.png"   // Update these paths
    ];
    const originalImages = [
        "images/clothes.png",
        "images/about.png",
        "images/contact.png"
    ];

    dropdownIcons.forEach((icon, index) => {
        const targetImage = document.querySelector(`#image${index + 1}`);

        icon.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor behavior
            if (targetImage) {
                // Fade out the current image
                targetImage.classList.add('fade-out');

                // After the fade out, change the src and fade in the new image
                setTimeout(() => {
                    targetImage.src = newImages[index];
                    targetImage.classList.remove('fade-out');
                }, 500); // Duration matches the CSS transition duration
            } else {
                console.error(`Image #image${index + 1} not found`);
            }
        });

        icon.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default anchor behavior
            if (targetImage) {
                // Fade out the current image
                targetImage.classList.add('fade-out');

                // After the fade out, change the src back to the original and fade in
                setTimeout(() => {
                    targetImage.src = originalImages[index];
                    targetImage.classList.remove('fade-out');
                }, 500); // Duration matches the CSS transition duration
            } else {
                console.error(`Image #image${index + 1} not found`);
            }
        });
    });
});


Without a code we can't really help you. If you could upload your code.

Yes sorry i forgot.

I recommend that you edit your images so that the hover and non-hover versions are the same size as each other.
